# Space between shapes in Raphaël JS

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am trying to use Raphaël to draw triangles on a canvas. The triangles have different shapes on them and cannot have any lines or shapes between each other.

My problem is that if I set `attr("stroke-width", 0)` I still get a small space between the triangles, although they are drawn with the same vertices.

It this a Raphaël "feature" or something that I ma doing wrong? Do I have to use something other than Raphaël to avoid this problem (like WebGL)?

Eg. these two triangles have a thin line (not black) between them.

```
paper.path("M100,100L200,100L100,200z").attr("fill", "#000").attr("stroke-width", 0);
paper.path("M200,200L200,100L100,200z").attr("fill", "#000").attr("stroke-width", 0);
```

The triangles above enlarged:

[image: Raphael example]

It seems to be some kind of anti-aliasing problem.

Comment: It is indeed antialiasing problem and in my opinion cannot be fixed. The one of the workarounds would be to make the triangles overlap a little

Comment: Thank you. The overlapping would probably work, but it would be problematic to do in my case. I am now going with WebGL, it should not do this (at least not according to the standard).